# store functions in variables Telegram source code

Tags: swift

I see this code in telegram open source app , how to create function like this and where is this application codes? this class is final and don't have delegate our protocol

```
 var vote:(MessageId, Data?) -> Void = { _, _ in }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a closure variable that you can assign your own closure to and your code will be executed whenever `vote` is called

```
var vote:(Int, String?) -> Void = { _, _ in }

vote = { (id, data) in print("\(id) \(data)") }

vote(32, "Hello")
```

Note that I changed the parameter types in my example since I am not familiar with `Telegram` classes

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you saw this, but this is closure variable. You can call it on class/struct where this `vote` is declared and then code inside closure will be called with certain parameters.

For example if you assign `vote` like this

```
someClass.vote = { messageId, data in // name parameters or not: _,data ; messageId,_ ; _,_
    print("Voted")
}
```

then if `vote` is called from inside of the class/struct

```
vote(someMessageId, someData)
```

... `"Voted"` gets printed.

---

So, this is useful delegate pattern replacement which allows you to declare from one class/struct what will happen when this closure gets called from another class/struct without declaring any protocol, assigning `delegate` and having extra methods.